# Xamarin Form 4.8 issue with ViewIsDisappearing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

ViewIsDisappearing gets called when we pull down the Notification Tray and ViewIsAppearing is called when we push the Notification Tray up.

This happens after upgrading our Xamarin Forms version to 4.8.0.1364 from 4.1.0

How do I prevent the calling of ViewIsDisappearing/ViewIsAppearing when the app is in Inactive state ? This was not there till 4.6

Comment: Did you use some third part library ?

Comment: Using Fresh MVVM 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

It has to be some other library triggering it, I just created a new project and tested but it the notification trail didn't trigger any of those events

Comment: Using Fresh MVVM 3.0.0

Comment: Did the same.... the OnDisappearing Event gets fired when i pull down the Notification tray...XF v 4.8.0.1364